# What is my problem to use of Conv2D for image?

Tags: python-3.x, keras, neural-network, conv-neural-network

First I read pictures from folders and sub-folders. Then I’m changing images to gray and resizing to 100*200. I want to classify my images to 6 class.
When i want to create my model, I can't  use Conv2D, cause I have dimension error but when I use Conv1D, I don’t have any error and neural network is work. 
I want to use conv2D because my data is image. What is my problem?

```
#load train_images
path_spec_train = "/home/narges/dataset/train_24/"
spec_train = glob.glob(path_spec_train + "**/*.png") 
spec_train.sort()

X_modify = []
width = 200
height = 100
for spec in spec_train:
    specs = cv2.imread(spec)
    specs = cv2.cvtColor(specs,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    specs = cv2.resize(specs ,(width, height))
    specs = specs / np.max(specs)
    specs = specs.astype(np.float32)
    X_modify.append(specs)

X_train = np.asarray(X_modify,dtype=np.float32)

#=======================================================
#load test_image

path_spec_test = "/home/narges/dataset/test_24/"
spec_test = glob.glob(path_spec_test + "**/*.png") 
spec_test.sort()

X_modify_t = []
width = 200
height = 100
for spec_t in spec_test:
    specs_test = cv2.imread(spec_t)
    specs_test = cv2.cvtColor(specs_test,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    specs_test = cv2.resize(specs_test ,(width, height))
    specs_test = specs_test / np.max(specs_test)
    specs_test = specs_test.astype(np.float32)
    X_modify_t.append(specs_test)

X_test = np.asarray(X_modify_t,dtype=np.float32)
#======================================================================
#label

spk_ID = [wavs[i].split('/')[-1].lower() for i in range(number_of_files)]

spk_ID_t = [wavs_t[i].split('/')[-1].lower() for i in range(number_of_files_t)]

label_no = [spk_ID[i].split('_')[-2] for i in range(number_of_files)]

Y_train = np_utils.to_categorical(label_no)

label_no_t = [spk_ID_t[i].split('_')[-2] for i in range(number_of_files_t)]

Y_test = np_utils.to_categorical(label_no_t)


#======================================================================
# Create my model
myinput = layers.Input(shape=(100,200))
conv1 = layers.Conv1D(32, 3, activation='relu', padding='same', strides=2)(myinput)
conv2 = layers.Conv1D(64, 3, activation='relu', padding='same', strides=2)(conv1)
flat = layers.Flatten()(conv2)
out_layer = layers.Dense(6, activation='softmax')(flat)
mymodel = Model(myinput, out_layer)
mymodel.summary()

mymodel.compile(optimizer=keras.optimizers.Adam(), loss=keras.losses.categorical_crossentropy, metrics=['accuracy'])

network_history = mymodel.fit(X_train, Y_train, batch_size=128, epochs=100)

pred = np.round(mymodel.predict(X_test))
print(classification_report(Y_test, pred))
```

Comment: What is the full error message that you get when using Conv2D? Also please include the shape of X_train.

Comment: I uploded my error and x_train in these links: https://pasteboard.co/ItobeQh.jpg , https://pasteboard.co/ItobyTw.jpg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add the channels dimension to your input training data:

```
import numpy as np

X_train = np.expand_dims(X_train, axis=3)
X_test = np.expand_Dims(X_test, axis=3)
```

Then your data will be 4D, for example, (3312, 100, 200, 1), which is a grayscale image (one channel).

Comment: Thanks. My problem is solved with this part of code. very very thanks.